# Prove that if $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\{x:f'(x)=0\}\subset \{x:f(x)=0\}$, then $f\equiv 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable with $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\{x:f'(x)=0\}\subset \{x:f(x)=0\}$. Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

My Work:
By Rolle's Theorem intituily I see that this is true. Or by Rolle's Theorem there are local minima and maxima, so $f$ is $0$ at those local minima and maxima. Hence, $f$ must be $0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. But how can I write a legible proof for this? Can anyone please help?

Comment: **Hint:** Assume $f$ to be different from being identicall $0$ in $[0,1]$, then $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and has a global supremum and a global infimum in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, thus there exists $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $$f(x_0)=\max_{x\in[0,1]}f(x).$$It follows that either $f'(x_0)=0,$ or $x_0\in\{0,1\}$. Either way, by assumption $f(x_0)=0,$ which yields $$\max_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)=0.$$An identical argument shows that$$\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq0$, then  take the sets
 $$L=\{x\in [0,x_0):f(x)=0\}$$
and
$$R=\{x\in (x_0,1]:f(x)=0\}$$

Then clearly by continuity $supL$ and $infR$ should belong to the above sets. Furthermore, by Rolle we have a new point $y$ with $f(y)=0$ and different from $x_0$, between those $supL$ and $infR$ which is a contradiction.